# how to have xampp Control Panel on web interface on linux?

Tags: xampp, controlpanel

I'm looking for a script that allows me to know if the service is running, it can stop or restart or start and control his mistakes.

All through web interface on a linux server.

Base should do what he does Xampp Control Panel on Windows with the possibility to also stop,  restart, configure and see logs of services.

I tried something like this, but I have not found anything that can be done through web interface.

Are any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terminal, type the following and hit enter.

gksu /opt/lampp/share/xampp-control-panel/xampp-control-panel

note: replace gksu by : kdesu for KDE3 / kdesudo for KDE 4
if any dependency error is displayed, you need to install the same. The msg will be self explanatory.

HTH